# pass html input element variable to shared component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hello I have two components. Component 1 has a input-element to upload videos. It has a variable file

```
<input
  type="file"
  accept=".mp4"
  #file
/>
```

Now I have Component2 which is a shared component:

```
<button (click)="file.click()">upload video</button>
```

Now I need the "file" variable passed to the shared component to execute the file.click();

I can't take the input element in the shared component

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9wi6qs?file=src/app/component1/component1.component.html

Comment: You thinking about this wrong. You should do data down actions up. You don't show how these two components relate to each other so it's hard to be specific. But you should be using `EventEmitter`, etc.

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I call the shared component "<app-upload-video-button></app-upload-video-button>" in the compoonent 1

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @Liam https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9wi6qs?file=src/app/component1/component1.component.html

Comment: In the question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as simple as sending the value into the component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
  templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component1.component.css']
})
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
   
  public fileAddress: string;

  public fileChanged(event) {
     // read the file when it changes and store it locally
     if(event.target.files.length > 0) 
         this.fileAddress = event.target.files[0].name;
     }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<!-- bind the event handler -->
<input type="file" accept=".mp4" (change)="fileChanged($event)" />
<!-- bind the local variable to an input on the child component -->
<app-upload-video [fileAddress]="fileAddress"></app-upload-video>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-video',
  templateUrl: './upload-video.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload-video.component.css']
})
export class UploadVideoComponent implements OnInit {

  //input variable to receive the value inside the component
  @Input()
  public fileAddress: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```